# RandomForestClassifier - index 1 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

I am following the example from the link below.

https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2015/09/build-predictive-model-10-minutes-python/

Here is my actual code.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import random
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn import datasets
from tabulate import tabulate
from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve
from sklearn.metrics import auc

# Load data
train = pd.read_csv('C:\\path_here\\train.csv')
test = pd.read_csv('C:\\path_here\\test.csv')

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)

train.shape
list(train)
test.shape
list(test)

df = pd.concat([train,test],axis=0) #Combined both Train and Test Data set
df.shape

df = train.select_dtypes(include=[np.number])
df.shape
list(df)
df.dtypes


features = [ 'block', 'zip', 'lot', 'schooldist', 'xcoord', 'ycoord']


df['target'] = 0
df.head(10)

#create label encoders for categorical features
for var in df:
    number = LabelEncoder()
    df[var] = number.fit_transform(df[var].astype('str'))

df['target__office'] = number.fit_transform(df['target'].astype('str'))


training, testing = np.split(df.sample(frac=1), [int(.8*len(df))])

print('Training set shape:', training.shape)
print('Testing set shape:', testing.shape)


x_train = training[list(features)].values
y_train = training['target'].values
x_validate = testing[list(features)].values
y_validate = testing['target'].values
x_test = test[list(features)].values


random.seed(100)
rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=1000)
rf.fit(x_train, y_train)


# Check performance and make predictions
status = rf.predict_proba(x_validate)
fpr, tpr, _ = roc_curve(y_validate, status[:,1])
roc_auc = auc(fpr, tpr)
print(roc_auc)

final_status = rf.predict_proba(x_test)
test['target__office']=final_status[:,1]
```

The error occurs on this line:

```
fpr, tpr, _ = roc_curve(y_validate, status[:,1])
```

This is the error message that I am seeing.

```
IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1
```

My x_validate looks like this:

```
x_validate
Out[812]: 
array([[479, 156,  24, ...,  91, 667,  44],
       [417,   0,  10, ...,  41, 177, 388],
       [810, 123,  14, ..., 447,  12,  78],
       ...,
       [201, 136,   7, ..., 266,  58, 448],
       [189,   0,  32, ...,   0, 961, 962],
       [ 63, 133,  19, ..., 548, 399, 400]])
```

My y_validate looks like this:

```
y_validate
Out[813]: 
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0])
```

Any idea what's wrong here?  I guess I just don't know this stuff well enough to trouble shoot the error myself.  Thanks!